# Настройка точки доступа на Wi-Fi ноутбука с NAT-ом

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

Хочу из ноутбука, на котором есть `Ethernet` и `Wi-Fi` настроить функционал, аналогичный Wi-Fi роутер-у с NAT-ом и пробросом портов, который будет брать интернет из PPPoE (ppp0), который в свою очередь получает его по Ethernet (enp0s10) и будет его раздавать по Wi-Fi (wlp5s0) имея возможность пробрасывать порты, то есть что бы некоторые порты, например http, был виден в интернете.

Использую `openSUSE Tumbleweed`, `SuseFirewall2` (в последствии и напрямую `iptables`), `systemd-networkd`, `hostapd`, `dnsmesq`.

Сеть настраиваю через systemd-networkd (wpa_supplicant остановлен)

```
[Match]
Name=en*
[Network]
Description=Ethernet
DHCP=yes
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4
IPForward=ipv4
#IPMasquerade=kernel
[DHCP]
RouteMetric=10

[Match]
Name=ppp*
[Network]
Description=PPPoE
IPForward=ipv4
#IPMasquerade=kernel
[DHCP]
RouteMetric=5

[Match]
Name=wl*
[Network]
Description=Wi-Fi
DHCP=no
Address=192.168.1.1/24
IPForward=ipv4
#IPMasquerade=kernel
[DHCP]
#RouteMetric=20
```

В SuseFirewall2 определил enp0s10 и ppp0 как внешние и wlp5s0 как внутренний, и отметил галочку разрешения сетевой передачи (`sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`) и натыкал его в сетевые настройки каждого интерфейса (`IPForward=ipv4`), так как читал, что systemd-networkd может её переопределять.

`sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` всегда выдаёт 1

hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlp5s0
driver=nl80211
ssid=ILYA
utf8_ssid=1
country_code=RU
hw_mode=g
channel=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
wmm_enabled=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=myPassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wps_state=0
ipaddr_type_availability=17
hs20=1
```

dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=wlp5s0
bind-interfaces
dhcp-range=192.168.1.100,192.168.1.200,12h
```

Точка доступа клиентам видна, к ней они успешно подключаются и получают IP.

```
sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
wlp5s0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
ACS: Automatic channel selection started, this may take a bit
wlp5s0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ACS
wlp5s0: ACS-STARTED
wlp5s0: ACS-COMPLETED freq=2412 channel=1
Using interface wlp5s0 with hwaddr 00:15:af:3d:8e:18 and ssid "ILYA"
wlp5s0: interface state ACS->ENABLED
wlp5s0: AP-ENABLED
wlp5s0: STA 84:8e:df:f2:5a:d2 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
wlp5s0: STA 84:8e:df:f2:5a:d2 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlp5s0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 84:8e:df:f2:5a:d2
wlp5s0: STA 84:8e:df:f2:5a:d2 RADIUS: starting accounting session 42A5DC7C41F38F95
wlp5s0: STA 84:8e:df:f2:5a:d2 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
```

Сервисы, находящиеся на ноутбуке клиенты видят, но интернета от ноутбука они не получают.

```
ping 8.8.8.8
From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 Destination Protocol Unreachable
.............................................................

sudo iptables -L FORWARD --line-numbers
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
2    forward_int  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
3    forward_ext  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
4    forward_ext  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
5    forward_ext  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
6    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-FWD-ILL-ROUTING "
7    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

То есть сама точка доступа, вроде, работает нормально (там в конфигурации чтолько странных настроек, что я не могу гарантировать что там всё правильно), а проблема, кажется в `iptables/SuseFirewall2`, хотя раньше на другом компе с несколькими ethernet-ами я таким же образом поднимал NAT без каких-либо проблем.

```
sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Jun 28 15:00:41 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [196917:16784076]
:INPUT ACCEPT [171757:15131945]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [198314:26166793]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2533:203080]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 411 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 4111
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 411 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 4111
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 666 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 6666
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 666 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 6666
-A POSTROUTING -o enp0s10 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o enp0s16 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o usbpn0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 28 15:00:41 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Jun 28 15:00:41 2017
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2753595:607681905]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2743047:606364372]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3194416:2062704411]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [3194419:2062704603]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 411 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 411 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 666 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 666 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 28 15:00:41 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Jun 28 15:00:41 2017
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2753595:607681905]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3194416:2062704411]
-A PREROUTING -i wlp5s0 -j CT --notrack
-A OUTPUT -o wlp5s0 -j CT --notrack
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 28 15:00:41 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Jun 28 15:00:41 2017
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3131619:2047600227]
:f2b-apache-auth - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-badbots - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-botsearch - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-fakegooglebot - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-nohome - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-noscript - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-overflows - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-shellshock - [0:0]
:f2b-dovecot - [0:0]
:f2b-php-url-fopen - [0:0]
:f2b-postfix-sasl - [0:0]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]
:f2b-sshd-ddos - [0:0]
:forward_ext - [0:0]
:forward_int - [0:0]
:input_ext - [0:0]
:input_int - [0:0]
:reject_func - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,587,993,995 -j f2b-postfix-sasl
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,587,993,995 -j f2b-dovecot
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-php-url-fopen
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-apache-shellshock
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-apache-fakegooglebot
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-apache-botsearch
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-apache-nohome
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-apache-overflows
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-apache-noscript
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-apache-badbots
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-apache-auth
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd-ddos
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -i wlp5s0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j input_ext
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-IN-ILL-TARGET " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
-A FORWARD -i wlp5s0 -j forward_int
-A FORWARD -i enp0s10 -j forward_ext
-A FORWARD -i enp0s16 -j forward_ext
-A FORWARD -i ppp0 -j forward_ext
-A FORWARD -i usbpn0 -j forward_ext
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-FWD-ILL-ROUTING " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -o wlp5s0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A f2b-apache-auth -j RETURN
-A f2b-apache-badbots -j RETURN
-A f2b-apache-botsearch -j RETURN
-A f2b-apache-fakegooglebot -j RETURN
-A f2b-apache-nohome -j RETURN
-A f2b-apache-noscript -j RETURN
-A f2b-apache-overflows -j RETURN
-A f2b-apache-shellshock -j RETURN
-A f2b-dovecot -j RETURN
-A f2b-php-url-fopen -j RETURN
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd-ddos -j RETURN
-A forward_ext -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 14 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 18 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 3/2 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 5 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -i enp0s10 -o wlp5s0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -i enp0s16 -o wlp5s0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -i ppp0 -o wlp5s0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -i usbpn0 -o wlp5s0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A forward_ext -m comment --comment "sfw2.insert.pos" -m pkttype ! --pkt-type unicast -j DROP
-A forward_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-FWDext-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A forward_ext -p icmp -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-FWDext-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A forward_ext -p udp -m limit --limit 3/min -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-FWDext-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A forward_ext -j DROP
-A forward_int -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 14 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 18 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 3/2 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m icmp --icmp-type 5 -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -i wlp5s0 -o enp0s10 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -i wlp5s0 -o enp0s16 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -i wlp5s0 -o ppp0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -i wlp5s0 -o usbpn0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A forward_int -m comment --comment "sfw2.insert.pos" -m pkttype ! --pkt-type unicast -j DROP
-A forward_int -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-FWDint-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A forward_int -p icmp -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-FWDint-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A forward_int -p udp -m limit --limit 3/min -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-FWDint-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A forward_int -j reject_func
-A input_ext -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j DROP
-A input_ext -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 80 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 443 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 3030:3033 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3030:3033 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 411 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 411 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 666 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 666 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 143 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 995 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 4046 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4046 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 6600 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6600 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 8000 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 23420 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23420 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 25 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 587 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 22 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 9999 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9999 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --dport 10000 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p udp -m udp --dport 3030:3033 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p udp -m udp --dport 411 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p udp -m udp --dport 666 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p udp -m udp --dport 23420 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p udp -m udp --dport 9999 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p udp -m udp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p udp -m udp --dport 10001 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -p udp -m udp --dport 10002 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -m limit --limit 3/min -m mark --mark 0x1 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-REDIR " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m mark --mark 0x1 -j ACCEPT
-A input_ext -m comment --comment "sfw2.insert.pos" -m pkttype ! --pkt-type unicast -j DROP
-A input_ext -p tcp -m limit --limit 3/min -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p icmp -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -p udp -m limit --limit 3/min -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
-A input_ext -j DROP
-A reject_func -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A reject_func -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A reject_func -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 28 15:00:41 2017
```

Попробовал указать правила вручную, но это только привело к ещё более худшему результату.

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp5s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

После этих команд у меня пропадает интернет на ноутбуке.

```
sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Jun 28 15:03:22 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [56:4021]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [25:3270]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [25:3270]
-A POSTROUTING -o wlp5s0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 28 15:03:22 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Jun 28 15:03:22 2017
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [283:31132]
:INPUT ACCEPT [280:30736]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [114:12295]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [114:12295]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 28 15:03:22 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Jun 28 15:03:22 2017
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2762306:609037401]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3206332:2067813109]
-A PREROUTING -i wlp5s0 -j CT --notrack
-A OUTPUT -o wlp5s0 -j CT --notrack
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 28 15:03:22 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Wed Jun 28 15:03:22 2017
*filter
:INPUT DROP [279:30688]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [112:11979]
:f2b-apache-auth - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-badbots - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-botsearch - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-fakegooglebot - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-nohome - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-noscript - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-overflows - [0:0]
:f2b-apache-shellshock - [0:0]
:f2b-dovecot - [0:0]
:f2b-php-url-fopen - [0:0]
:f2b-postfix-sasl - [0:0]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]
:f2b-sshd-ddos - [0:0]
:forward_ext - [0:0]
:forward_int - [0:0]
:input_ext - [0:0]
:input_int - [0:0]
:reject_func - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i ppp0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 28 15:03:22 2017
```

Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в правилах `iptables` и прошу Вашей помощи.
А если проблема не в правилах `iptables`, тогда помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться куда же мне копать?

Comment: https://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=103646

Comment: *Попробовал указать правила вручную* — после этого выполните `$ sudo iptables-save` и приложите вывод к вопросу.

Comment: Благодарю, приложил и до и после.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin В предлагаемой ссылке предлагается включить нат вот так sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
Если я правильно понимаю, тут дополнительно ограничивается диапазон адресов, что мне делать не хотелось бы в правилах, а также из этого следует что в моих командах выше sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp5s0 -j MASQUERADE перепутаны местами внешние и внутренние интерфейсы. Это так?

Answer (score 1):

для цепочек `INPUT` и `FORWARD` в таблице `filter` у вас установлены политики `DROP`:

> ```
> *filter
> :INPUT DROP [279:30688]
> :FORWARD DROP [0:0]
> ```

раз вы очищаете все правила *netfilter*-а, то надо изменить и политики этих цепочек на `ACCEPT`, иначе через эти цепочки вообще не будут пакеты ходить. общий синтаксис команды:

```
iptables -t таблица -P цепочка политика
```

если таблица — `filter`, то можно её не указывать (подразумевается по умолчанию). пример:

```
$ sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

---

см. документацию по программе *iptables* — `$ man iptables`

---

более «правильно», наверно, всё-таки продолжить пользоваться [менеджером *susefirewall*](https://ru.opensuse.org/SuSEfirewall2) (или удалить его совсем, чтоб не мешался под ногами). тогда вам надо как-то его сконфигурировать, чтобы он добавлял нужные вам правила *netfilter*-а. я тут ничего подсказать не смогу — всяких этих «[дырявых абстракций](http://russian.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/LeakyAbstractions.html)», якобы облегчающих жизнь, понапридумано столько, что за всю жизнь во все эти абстракции вникнуть не удастся.

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку. Ближе к ночи попробую это сделать.